# Solr-Retrieve name of document where the word is found

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am using queries (Solr Admin) to search words through two text documents that are in my HDFS. How can i retrieve the name of the document that the word is found in. I am using this project https://github.com/lucidworks/hadoop-solr

I am creating a collection using `bin/solr -e cloud` and i am using *"data_driven_schema_configs"* from *server/solr/configsets/* directory.

I tryied  adding `<field name="fileName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />`  inside *managed-schema* at                      *~/solr-6.1.0/server/solr/configsets/data_driven_schema_configs/conf*, and  also change it name to *schema.xml*, but in this directory there isn't any dataConfig file to add `<field column="file" name="fileName"/>` as i see it in some other posts with similar questions, but not for SolrCloud, so i don't know if that i am trying is correct. What changes, and in which directories, i have to do, to be able to make it happen.

Example: I am searching the word "greatest" which can found in both documents. How can i see in which document is every result, *sample1.txt* or *sample2.txt*

[image]

Comment: If those are the only fields in your index that describes the documents, you can't. How did you generate the index files? Those `id` values seems to be actual text from the documents, and not suitable unique ids.

Comment: I am using this project  https://github.com/LucidWorks/hadoop-solr @MatsLindh

Comment: You should start reading Solr basics before asking. As @MatsLindh said, the first thing is that you should provide suitable unique ids for the `id` field. The actual text from the documents should be indexed in an apropriated text field, see [Solr Field Types](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Solr+Field+Types). Also if you want the name of the matched documents, why not indexing & storing the name of the documents ?

Comment: @Spyros_av please provide a sample of the data you send to Solr, with the update request. Are you runnning Solr in schemaless mode ?

Comment: @n0tting i forgot to mention that i am using SolrCloud. The data that i am using is same books in .txt format from https://www.gutenberg.org/

Answer (score 3):

Same thing I said when you mentioned this question on IRC:

Your Solr schema must contain a field where you put the name, set to stored="true", and you must include that field, with a relevant value, in every document when you index.  Most schema changes require a full reindex.

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/HowToReindex

Comment: i have added this line, at manged-schema `<field name="fileName" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />` at this directory: `/solr-6.1.0/server/solr/configsets/data_driven_schema_configs/conf ` is that what you mean?

Comment: And did you assure that this field is not only present, but also filled during the indexing process? And how should old documents of your index get a value into that field? Someone needs to write it in there. Henceforth, did you re-index after the schema extension?

Comment: @elyograg what do you mean with that " and you must include that field, with a relevant value, in every document when you index."

Comment: In order for a field to actually be useful, it must be populated.  For the specific example (seeing a filename when indexing files) it's particularly important that every document actually include a filename field, and that the filename field has something useful in it.